# How to hide\show specific value of option based on another selected option by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have html select form like this:

```
<label>Num:</label>
<select id="id_num">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value=''>all</option>
</select>
<label>Choices:</label>
<select id="id_choices">
    <option value='car'>car</option>
    <option value='bike'>bike</option>
    <option value='house'>house</option>
    <option value='money'>money</option>
    <option value='plane'>plane</option>
    <option value='wife'>wife</option>
</select>
```

In my case I need to make it so that if I choose "1" at the first select form (# id_num), then the next select form (#id_choices) should only show "car" and "bike" options, and if I choose "2", #id_choices should only show "house" and "money", and also the rest.. But if i select "all", then every options on #id_choices should be shown.

How to solve that condition by using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to filter your options, and make them `display: none;` depending upon the occurence of the item in the array,

Please have a look on the code below:

```js
$(function() {


    $('#id_num').on('change', function(e) {

        if ($(this).val() == 1) {

            var arr = ['car', 'bike'];
            $('#id_choices option').each(function(i) {
                if ($.inArray($(this).attr('value'), arr) == -1) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
                }
            });
        } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {

            var arr = ['house', 'money'];
            $('#id_choices option').each(function(i) {
                if ($.inArray($(this).attr('value'), arr) == -1) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
                }
            });
        } else if ($(this).val() == 3) {

            var arr = ['plane', 'wife'];
            $('#id_choices option').each(function(i) {
                if ($.inArray($(this).attr('value'), arr) == -1) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
                }
            });
        } else {

            $('#id_choices option').each(function(i) {
                $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
            });

        }

    })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Num:</label>
<select id="id_num">
    <option disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value=''>all</option>
</select>
<label>Choices:</label>
<select id="id_choices">
    <option value='car'>car</option>
    <option value='bike'>bike</option>
    <option value='house' >house</option>
    <option value='money' >money</option>
    <option value='plane' >plane</option>
    <option value='wife' >wife</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Faizalprbw - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: can we replace the use of css display by show\hide instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a function once when the page loads and then every time `#id_num` changes, such that all the visible `#id_choices` options are removed (using `remove()`), and then only the relevant options are re-added to `#id_choices` (using `append()`) to replace them.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var car = '<option value="car">car</option>';
  var bike = '<option value="bike">bike</option>';
  var house = '<option value="house">house</option>';
  var money = '<option value="money">money</option>';
  var plane = '<option value="plane">plane</option>';
  var wife = '<option value="wife">wife</option>';

    function options1() {
        $('#id_choices').append(car);
        $('#id_choices').append(bike);
    }

    function options2() {
        $('#id_choices').append(house);
        $('#id_choices').append(money);
    }

    function options3() {
        $('#id_choices').append(plane);
        $('#id_choices').append(wife);
    }

    function displayOptions() {

        $('#id_choices option').remove();

        switch ($('#id_num option:selected' ).text()) {
            case('1') : options1(); break;
            case('2') : options2(); break;
            case('3') : options3(); break;
            case('all') : options1(); options2(); options3(); break;
        }
    }

    $('#id_num').change(function(){displayOptions();});

    displayOptions();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Num:</label>
<select id="id_num">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value=''>all</option>
</select>
<label>Choices:</label>
<select id="id_choices">
    <option value='car'>car</option>
    <option value='bike'>bike</option>
    <option value='house'>house</option>
    <option value='money'>money</option>
    <option value='plane'>plane</option>
    <option value='wife'>wife</option>
</select>
```

---

For the sake of completeness, here is the same approach as above, but this time in native javascript, so you can compare and contrast with the jQuery above:

```js
var numbers = document.getElementById('id_num');
var choices = document.getElementById('id_choices');

function displayOptions() {

    var optionSet1 = ['car', 'bike'];
    var optionSet2 = ['house', 'money'];
    var optionSet3 = ['plane', 'wife'];
    var oldOptions = choices.getElementsByTagName('option');
    var selected = numbers.options[numbers.selectedIndex].text;

    while (oldOptions.length > 0) {
        choices.removeChild(oldOptions[0]);
    }

    switch (selected) {
        case('1') : var optionSet = optionSet1; break;
        case('2') : optionSet = optionSet2; break;
        case('3') : optionSet = optionSet3; break;
        case('all') : optionSet = optionSet1.concat(optionSet2).concat(optionSet3); break;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < optionSet.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value',optionSet[i]);
        option.textContent = optionSet[i];
        choices.appendChild(option);
    }
}

numbers.addEventListener('change',displayOptions,false);
window.addEventListener('load',displayOptions,false);
```

```html
<label>Num:</label>
<select id="id_num">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value=''>all</option>
</select>
<label>Choices:</label>
<select id="id_choices">
    <option value='car'>car</option>
    <option value='bike'>bike</option>
    <option value='house'>house</option>
    <option value='money'>money</option>
    <option value='plane'>plane</option>
    <option value='wife'>wife</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i think i would be better to use native javascript based on your answer below.. initialize of html script inside javascript variable on jquery example below better avoided in my opinion.. Thank you very much, if only i can add more the one correct answer..

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `display` with a value of `none` using `.prop()` instead of using `disabled` attribute (like in Saumya's answer) in case you want them completely invisible instead of just disabled/grayed-out

Answer (score 0):

there may be a better way, however this does work.. you can also add hide/display classes to any other elements

```js
        $(document).ready(function () { $('#id_num').on('change', change) });

        function change() {
            $('#id_choices > option').hide();
            $($(this).find(':selected').attr('clssval')).show();
        }
```

```css
.sel{display:none;}
.num1{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Num:</label>
<select id="id_num">
    <option value='1' clssval=".num1">1</option>
    <option value='2' clssval=".num2">2</option>
    <option value='3' clssval=".num3">3</option>
    <option value='' clssval=".num1,.num2,.num3">all</option>
</select>
<label>Choices:</label>
<select id="id_choices">
    <option value='car' class="sel num1">car</option>
    <option value='bike' class="sel num1">bike</option>
    <option value='house' class="sel num2">house</option>
    <option value='money' class="sel num2">money</option>
    <option value='plane' class="sel num3">plane</option>
    <option value='wife' class="sel num3">wife</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this can be use for other condition, but in my case, i can't add clssval caused of the using of django form in my template..

Comment: Have you tried? I know most lang. Even angular allows you to add attributes.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/  ,yes we can, but i have to split this {{ form.num }} into html form like example above manually.